# converting Joda time Instant to Java time Instant

Tags: java, time, jodatime, java-time, java.time.instant

I have an instance of Instant (org.joda.time.Instant) which I get in some api response. I have another instance from (java.time.Instant) which I get from some other call. Now, I want to compare these two object to check which one get the latest one. How would it be possible?

Comment: for comparison you could get the millis from each

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`getMillis()` from joda.time can be compared to `toEpochMilli()` from java.time.

Class documentation:

- [org.joda.time.Instant::getMillis](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html#getMillis--)
- [java.time.Instant::toEpochMilli](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--)

Example code.

```
java.time.Instant myJavaInstant = 
    java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli( myJodaInstant.getMillis() ) ;
```

Going the other way.

```
// Caution: Loss of data if the java.time.Instant has microsecond
// or nanosecond fraction of second.
org.joda.time.Instant myJodaInstant = 
    new org.joda.time.Instant( myJavaInstant.toEpochMilli() );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert from joda Instant to java's (*the datetime and formatting are just an example*):

```
org.joda.time.Instant.parse("10.02.2017 13:45:32", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")).toDate().toInstant()
```

So you call `toDate()` and `toInstant()` on your joda Instant.

Comment: the call to `parse` makes this answer confusing, but actually calling `toDate` returns a `java.util.Date`, which can be used to get the Instant...

Comment: hence the brackets: (the datetime and formatting are just an example)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in the Joda-Time sdk. It changes the time and time zone when you convert this way.

My original ISO string is:
originalISOString = 2023-08-02T22:00:00.000+01:00

I run the step above as:
org.joda.time.Instant.parse(originalISOString,
ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()).toDate().toInstant();

but after running through the step above, my resulting string (using Instant.toString()) is 2023-08-02T21:00:00Z

It has changed the time and the time zone.

Comment: The output is correct. It's not a bug; it's the expected behaviour. An `Instant` gives you a date-time denoting a moment at UTC (which is specified by a `Z`).

Comment: So your answer is that there is a bug in Joda-Time SDK? Apparently not, according to the comment to your answer. So how does your answer help anybody who is experiencing this problem? Your answer seems more suitable as a comment - but you can't comment as you don't have enough reputation. Maybe consider deleting this answer?